# How do i wrap structs that contain struct pointers in CFFI?

Tags: c, opencv, struct, common-lisp, cffi

The [IplImage struct documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=iplimage#iplimage) describes the `IplROI* roi` slot and it seems to be a pointer to the `IplROI struct` defined here in the core `types_c.h` header file:

```
 typedef struct _IplROI
     {
         int  coi; /* 0 - no COI (all channels are selected)
                    , 1 - 0th channel is selected ...*/
         int  xOffset;
         int  yOffset;
         int  width;
         int  height;
      }IplROI;
```

but it also describes the `IplImage* maskROI` slot and in the core `types_c.h` file there is no typedef struct for that...

if some one could help me find it i would appreciate it but i did grep the entire opencv download and found nothing.....Im attempting to wrap the IplImage struct with lisp
and i wrapped it with swig and got this

```
(cffi:defcstruct ipl-image
    (n-size :int)
    (id :int)
    (n-channels :int)
    (alpha-channel :int)
    (depth :int)
    (color-model :pointer) 
    (channel-seq :pointer) 
    (data-order :int)
    (origin :int)
    (align :int)
    (width :int)
    (height :int)
    (roi (:pointer (:struct ipl-roi)))
    (mask-roi :pointer)
    (image-id :pointer)
    (tile-info :pointer)
    (image-size :int)
    (image-data :string)
    (width-step :int)
    (border-mode :pointer)
    (border-const :pointer)
    (image-data-origin :string))
```

i changed it a bit here

```
   (cffi:defcstruct ipl-image
       (n-size :int)
       (id :int)
       (n-channels :int)
       (alpha-channel :int)
       (depth :int)
       (color-model :int) ;;Ignored by OpenCV - was :pointer, 
                              changed to :int so the struct values 
                              would match OpenCV's
       (channel-seq :int) ;;Ignored by OpenCV - was :pointer, 
                              changed to :int so the struct values 
                              would match OpenCV's
       (data-order :int)
       (origin :int)
       (align :int)
       (width :int)
       (height :int)
       (roi (:pointer (:struct ipl-roi))) ;; changed so i could access (:struct ipl-roi)
       (mask-roi :pointer)
       (image-id :pointer)
       (tile-info :pointer)
       (image-size :int)
       (image-data :string)
       (width-step :int)
       (border-mode :pointer)
       (border-const :pointer)
       (image-data-origin :string))
```

so when i ran the below code in emacs(shown with output) all the slot values 
would match the opencv output from the exact same code, which they do and so i could access
the ipl-roi struct with the ipl-image struct using this line

```
(roi (:pointer (:struct ipl-roi))) ;;
```

because my gut tells me its the right way

```
                        ; SLIME 2012-05-25
CL-OPENCV> (size-of '(:struct ipl-image))
128
CL-OPENCV> (defparameter img-size (make-size :width 640 :height 480))
(defparameter img (create-image img-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 3))

IMG
CL-OPENCV> (cffi:with-foreign-slots ((n-size id n-channels 
                         alpha-channel depth color-model 
                         channel-seq data-order origin  
                         align width height roi 
                         mask-roi image-id tile-info 
                         image-size image-data width-step 
                         border-mode border-const image-data-origin) 

                     img (:struct ipl-image))
         (format t "n-size = ~a~%id = ~a~%n-channels = 
                                ~a~%alpha-channel = ~a~%depth = ~a~%color-model = 
                                ~a~%channel-seq = ~a~%data-order = ~a~%origin = ~
                                a~%align = ~a~%width = ~a~%height = ~a~%roi = ~a~
                                %mask-roi = ~a~%image-id = ~a~%tile-info = ~a~%
                                image-size = ~a~%image-data = ~a~%width-step = 
                                ~a~%border-mode = ~a~%border-const = ~a~%image-
                                data-origin = ~a~%" 
             n-size id n-channels 
             alpha-channel depth color-model 
             channel-seq data-order origin  
             align width height roi 
             mask-rOI image-id tile-info 
             image-size image-data width-step 
             border-mode border-const image-data-origin))
n-size = 144
id = 0
n-channels = 3
alpha-channel = 0
depth = 8
color-model = 4343634
channel-seq = 5392194
data-order = 0
origin = 0
align = 4
width = 640
height = 480
roi = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000)
mask-roi = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000)
image-id = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000)
tile-info = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000)
image-size = 921600
image-data = 
width-step = 1920
border-mode = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000)
border-const = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000)
image-data-origin = NIL
NIL
CL-OPENCV>
```

but for the IplImage* maskROI  slot there is no struct to wrap so i was hoping some one could give me a quick lesson on how to wrap structs that contain struct pointers in CFFI and if i'm right in thinking this line

```
(roi (:pointer (:struct ipl-roi)))
```

is the right  thing to do and how to use it

I would really apreciate any help on this

Edit

Answer (score 0):

Blimey that question is too long!

Anyway the official documentation for this area of cffi is pretty bad.
I would recommend [looking at this file for lots of examples of different kinds of structs with various contents](https://github.com/cbaggers/classimp/blob/master/low-level.lisp)

For example:

```
(cffi:defcstruct ai-node-anim  ;; this is a definition of a c struct
  (m-node-name (:struct ai-string))
  (m-num-position-keys :unsigned-int)
  (m-position-keys (:pointer (:struct ai-vector-key))) ;; here is a pointer to a struct
  (m-num-rotation-keys :unsigned-int)
  (m-rotation-keys (:pointer (:struct ai-quat-key))) ;; here is a pointer to a struct
  (m-num-scaling-keys :unsigned-int)
  (m-scaling-keys (:pointer (:struct ai-vector-key))) ;; here is a pointer to a struct
  (m-pre-state ai-anim-behaviour)
  (m-post-state ai-anim-behaviour))
```

Hope it helps!